# cannot coerce class ‘"by"’ to a data.frame (R)

Tags: r, list

I have the given lists and vector :

```
Spec <- c("Calanus finmarchicus", "Calanus glacialis", "Calanus hyperboreus", 
"Calanus spp.", "Copepoda", "Metridia longa", "Microcalanus pusillus", 
"Microcalanus spp.", "Microsetella norvegica", "Oithona similis", 
"Oithona spp.", "Oncaea borealis", "Pseudocalanus spp.", "Microcalanus pygmaeus", 
"Pareuchaeta glacialis", "Calanoida indet.", "Oithona atlantica", 
"Pseudocalanus minutus", "Pareuchaeta spp.", "Acartia spp.")
ZoodataL50 <- structure(list(Transect = c("1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", 
"4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4"), Station = c("1", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1"
), Species = c("Calanus finmarchicus", "Calanus glacialis", "Calanus hyperboreus", 
"Calanus spp.", "Pareuchaeta glacialis", "Calanus finmarchicus", 
"Calanus glacialis", "Calanus hyperboreus", "Calanus spp.", "Calanus finmarchicus", 
"Calanus glacialis", "Calanus hyperboreus", "Calanus finmarchicus", 
"Calanus glacialis", "Calanus hyperboreus", "Calanus finmarchicus", 
"Calanus glacialis", "Microcalanus spp.", "Calanus finmarchicus", 
"Calanus glacialis", "Calanus hyperboreus", "Calanus spp.", "Oncaea borealis", 
"Pseudocalanus spp.", "Calanus finmarchicus", "Calanus glacialis", 
"Calanus hyperboreus", "Microcalanus spp."), mean_turb = c(51.7, 
51.7, 51.7, 51.7, 51.7, 15, 15, 15, 15, 185.1, 185.1, 185.1, 
293.7, 293.7, 293.7, 2.1, 2.1, 2.1, 3.6, 3.6, 3.6, 3.6, 3.6, 
3.6, 14.9, 14.9, 14.9, 14.9), Rel_biom = c(0.425798412200999, 
0.0894303667726106, 0.0982034104785712, 0.0121735930667325, 0.0289298177369833, 
0.691934975888281, 0.177489780335863, 0.106622503989315, 0.25405181232058, 
0.349900172337648, 0.444028340606541, 0.116759738674243, 0.191825202881111, 
0.077277494854345, 0.102549858501126, 0.00681106641422225, 0.00613391314191942, 
0.00612500553647714, 0.026707131460647, 0.0371160659539919, 0.0367832608206733, 
0.00461676295740788, 0.0103411034459642, 0.0079667991705717, 
0.0150774967105538, 0.0350675898070042, 0.0227696283037591, 0.00261294954249131
), frequency = c(0.509876294828541, 0.107089229899832, 0.117594593214932, 
0.0145773829816114, 0.034642281077448, 0.214709581947223, 0.0550756326299232, 
0.0330852956642681, 0.0788330700384962, 0.108575115211415, 0.137783379517648, 
0.0362309112165206, 0.0595239589741372, 0.0239794477693581, 0.0318215410620878, 
0.0293020150757093, 0.0263888214307096, 0.0263504998562182, 0.114897245320459, 
0.159677715352168, 0.15824594821899, 0.019861861498878, 0.0444886528254054, 
0.0342741143903377, 0.0648651780863677, 0.150864928148107, 0.0979576400006712, 
0.0112412186623629)), row.names = c(NA, -28L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))

Ll <- structure(list(`1 1` = c("Copepoda", "Metridia longa", "Microcalanus pusillus", 
"Microcalanus spp.", "Microsetella norvegica", "Oithona similis", 
"Oithona spp.", "Oncaea borealis", "Pseudocalanus spp.", "Microcalanus pygmaeus", 
"Calanoida indet.", "Oithona atlantica", "Pseudocalanus minutus", 
"Pareuchaeta spp.", "Acartia spp."), `1 2` = c("Copepoda", "Metridia longa", 
"Microcalanus pusillus", "Microcalanus spp.", "Microsetella norvegica", 
"Oithona similis", "Oithona spp.", "Oncaea borealis", "Pseudocalanus spp.", 
"Microcalanus pygmaeus", "Pareuchaeta glacialis", "Calanoida indet.", 
"Oithona atlantica", "Pseudocalanus minutus", "Pareuchaeta spp.", 
"Acartia spp."), `4 1` = c("Copepoda", "Metridia longa", "Microcalanus pusillus", 
"Microsetella norvegica", "Oithona similis", "Oithona spp.", 
"Microcalanus pygmaeus", "Pareuchaeta glacialis", "Calanoida indet.", 
"Oithona atlantica", "Pseudocalanus minutus", "Pareuchaeta spp.", 
"Acartia spp.")), .Dim = 3L, .Dimnames = list(`Reduce(paste, ZoodataL50[1:2])` = c("1 1", 
"1 2", "4 1")), call = by.default(data = ZoodataL50$Species, 
    INDICES = Reduce(paste, ZoodataL50[1:2]), FUN = setdiff, 
    x = Spec), class = "by")
```

And I would like to do have the list `Ll` in data frame in order to do a `pivot_longer()` with the different columns. Nevertheless, when I try to apply that code `Ll <- as.data.frame(Ll)`, I obtain the error `Error in as.data.frame.default(Sp_Biom_L1Turb) :  cannot coerce class ‘"by"’ to a data.frame`.

Then I have tried to transform it first in matrix before with `Ll <- as.matrix(as.data.frame(Ll))`. But the result is the same.

Comment: I have uploaded Spec. I have also cleaned my environment and run the code, that should work properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could use `base R`

```
out <- data.frame(ID = rep(names(Ll), lengths(Ll)), Col1 = unlist(Ll))
row.names(out) <- NULL
```

-output

```
> head(out)
   ID                   Col1
1 1 1               Copepoda
2 1 1         Metridia longa
3 1 1  Microcalanus pusillus
4 1 1      Microcalanus spp.
5 1 1 Microsetella norvegica
6 1 1        Oithona similis
```

---

Or with `tidyverse`

```
library(tibble)
library(purrr)
map_dfr(Ll, enframe, .id = 'ID')
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 44 × 3
   ID     name value                 
   <chr> <int> <chr>                 
 1 1 1       1 Copepoda              
 2 1 1       2 Metridia longa        
 3 1 1       3 Microcalanus pusillus 
 4 1 1       4 Microcalanus spp.     
 5 1 1       5 Microsetella norvegica
 6 1 1       6 Oithona similis       
 7 1 1       7 Oithona spp.          
 8 1 1       8 Oncaea borealis       
 9 1 1       9 Pseudocalanus spp.    
10 1 1      10 Microcalanus pygmaeus 
# … with 34 more rows
```

Comment: The first one works properly and for the second I must apply first a `matrix()` to make it works. 
Also to preserve the "id" of the columns it is necessary to 
-unlist column by column `Col1 = unlist(Ll[["1 1"]])`; 
-add an id `df$name="1_1"`; 
-and after gather the extracted column with `rbind()`.

Comment: @C.Guffens sorry, I tried it after removing the attribute for second case.  Can you try the updated one